# Call base class override method from base constructor C#

Tags: c#, constructor, polymorphism, overriding

I want to have class which will have an indexer and number of fields like in the following example:

```
public abstract class ARecord
{        
    public abstract double this[int index] { get; }
    public abstract int NumberOfFields { get; }
}

public class Record : ARecord
{
    public double Field1{ get; private set; }
    public double Field2{ get; private set; }

    public override int NumberOfFields { get { return 2; } }

    public Record(double[] records)
    {
        if (records.Count() != NumberOfFields) // PROBLEM IS HERE. WHEN CALLING THIS FROM DERIVED CLASS NumberOfFields=3!
            throw new ArgumentException();
        this.Field1= records[0];
        this.Field2 = records[1];
    }

    public override double this[int index]
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }     
}

public class ChildRecord : Record
{
    public double Field3 { get; private set; }

    public override int NumberOfFields { get { return 3; } }

    public ChildRecord(double[] records)
        : base(new double[] { records[0], records[1] })
    {
        if (records.Count() != NumberOfFields)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        this.Field3 = records[2];
    }

    public override double this[int index]
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }     
}

public static class TestRecord
{
    public static void CreateRecord()
    {
        var record = new ChildRecord(new double[]{1.0,1.5,2.5}); // Not working
    }
}
```

This example crashes because of polymorphic call `NumberOfFields` from `ChildRecord` inside constructor of `Record`.

As far as I know, I can use `new` insted of `override` to solve this problem, but in that case I cannot declare `NumberOfFields` as `abstract` in base class (which I needed).

What is the proper way to solve this problem? Is something wrong with the design?

Comment: What about virtual keyword?

Comment: @OrcusZ Where to put virtual? You cannot override abstract method with virtual keyword

Comment: Change abstract by virtual. You will be able to override them. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual

Comment: @OrcusZ You cannot use virtual method without implementation in abstract class. `ARecord` is abstract class.

Comment: Whether something is wrong with the design is hard to say - I guess it depends on what you're trying to achieve with it. What is the point of validating that the number of fields is exactly two in Record? And why not simply have two constructor arguments then, i.e. why does it have to be a list?
One way of fixing the concrete error you're seeing is to introduce a check in Record to see if it's actually a record being created, e.g.
if (this.GetType() == typeof(Record) && records.Count() != NumberOfFields)
so that the validation only takes place if the constructor is invoked directly.

Comment: @kkirk Point of validating the number of fields and length of array is to avoid wrong call, i.e. if I call constructor for `Record` by passing array with 1000 element it will work, but it is wrong call, since I used only two elements. `this.GetType() == typeof(Record)` will results only in validating arguments in directly `Record` creation, without validating calls from derived class, so it is not a general solution.

Comment: @Petar Ok, but the child class validates its own arguments, correct? If you need to be able to further derive ChildRecord, it will have to have a similar validation condition of course. The point is that if Record constructor is invoked directly, the validation makes sense, and otherwise it should skip it, since the numberoffields == 2 condition does not make sense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've formulated this, it cannot possibly work as intended. Assume it *did* (through some sort of some magic) work the way you think it should, and you were able to create your `ChildRecord`:

```
var record = new ChildRecord(new double[] { 1.0, 1.5, 2.5 });
```

What would you expect the value of `record.NumberOfFields` to be? Two or three? This particular object cannot be a `ChildRecord` with `NumberOfFields == 3` and at the same time be a `Record` with `NumberOfFields == 2`. You get the result of the `NumberOfFields` implementation of the instantiated class, regardless of whether you type `record` as `ARecord`, `Record` or `ChildRecord`.

To put it another way: It makes no sense to expose `ARecord.NumberOfFields` to the outside, as there is no one correct answer -- it isn't a meaningful concept.

If you abstain from exposing it, you can do your validation something like this (with indexers and properties omitted):

```
public abstract class ARecord
{
    public abstract double this[int index] { get; }
}

public class Record : ARecord
{
    private const int NumberOfFields = 2;

    public Record(double[] records)
    {
        if (records.Count() != NumberOfFields)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        this.Field1 = records[0];
        this.Field2 = records[1];
    }
}

public class ChildRecord : Record
{
    private const int NumberOfFields = 3;

    public ChildRecord(double[] records)
        : base(new double[] { records[0], records[1] })
    {
        if (records.Count() != NumberOfFields)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        this.Field3 = records[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it makes no sense to expose `ARecord.NumberOfFields`. How you will use class with only indexer? E.g. `ARecord record;` `for(int i =0; i <???;i++) Console.WriteLine(record[i]);` or similar?

Comment: I expect that `record.NumberOfFields` will be two or three depending of the instantiated class when calling from outside. It makes sense for me. And then I can use indexer since I know how many fields my class has.

Comment: Yes, `NumberOfFields` is two or three depending on the instantiated class. That's why, when you create a `ChildRecord`, `NumberOfFields` is three. I am not sure why you're surprised by this. If you create a `Record` instead, the value will be two.

Comment: When you call `super` from `ChildRecord`'s constructor, the instance doesn't magically change -- it is still a `ChildRecord`. That's how polymorphism works.

Comment: So using `NumberOfFields` to control looping over the indexer would work the way you want. But you can't "underride" the overridden `NumberOfFields` in your `Record` base class.

Comment: I can use something like `if (records.Count() != 2)...` instead of calling `NumberOfFields` property in constructor to solve the problem. But when I have such ugly solution it usually means that there is something wrong with the design. What you are saying is that there is no better solution than avoid calling this property inside the constructor.

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: About your design, I don't really know what you're aiming for. Seems a bit unusual, though.